# Showing a function is Lipschitz continuous and finding the the constant

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, lipschitz-functions

Consider the Gaussian kernel function K(i,j) defined by

$$
K(i,j)= e^{-\alpha*\left \| x_i-x_j \right \|} 
$$
where $x_i$ is a point in a $R^d$ space.

Show K is Lipschitz continuous. I know the definition for Lipschitz continuous, but I don't know how to use it here. Has someone a hint?

Comment: This question is not 100% clear. So, the function that you want to prove is Lipschitz: is it $f$ with domain $\mathbb{R}^{2d}$, with $$f(x, y) = e^{-\alpha ||x - y||}$$ where $x, y$ are members of $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Norm is Lipschitz. $e^{-x}$ is Lipschitz. So gaussian kernel can be seen as a composition of two Lipschitz functions. As pointed out by the other comment, the domain of the Kernel needs to be changed.

Comment: THE DOMAIN IS IN THE $R^d$ and the codomain is in R  @Ovi

Comment: @Kumar you can consider each node of the graphs in a d dimension space and you want to reweight the edges of the graph based on this function. the question is that is this function a Lipshitz function